# query has no destination for result data - not answered by similar questions

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a function that calls 3 helper functions. One of the helper functions returns an integer, the other helper functions return void. When I call the helper function by itself, it executes and returns a value. When I try to call it within the wrapper function, it throws the error.

Helper function:

```
create or replace function create_battery_asset()
returns int
as $$
    declare 
        battery_type_id integer := (select id from asset_type_tb where "type" ilike 'battery');
    
        bat_cap_type integer := (select id from process_type_tb where subtype = 'battery' and subtype2 = 'capacitance');
        bat_res_type integer := (select id from process_type_tb where subtype = 'battery' and subtype2 = 'internal resistance');                                                           -- 
        
        bat_cap_ps integer := (select randchoice(array(select id from process_tb where type_id = bat_cap_type and id > 17)));
        bat_res_ps integer := (select randchoice(array(select id from process_tb where type_id = bat_res_type and id > 17)));
        
    
    begin
        insert into asset_tb("owner", "type_id", "process_id", "serial_number", "common_name", "eol", "units")
            values (current_user, battery_type_id, array[bat_cap_ps, bat_res_ps], (select upper(substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 7))), 'tarot battery', 7000, 'amp-hours');
        
    return (select id from asset_tb where "type_id" = (select id from asset_type_tb where "type" ilike 'battery') order by id desc limit 1)::integer;
        
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

wrapper function

```
create or replace function replace_battery(uav_id int)
returns void
as $$
    declare 
        -- different ways I have tried this
        -- batt_id int := create_battery_asset()
        -- batt_id int := (select * from create_battery_asset());
        -- batt_id int: (select create_battery_asset());
        batt_id int;
    begin
        -- different ways I have tried this
        -- execute 'select create_battery_asset();' into batt_id;
        -- select into batt_id create_battery_asset();
        -- select create_battery_asset() into batt_id;
        select into batt_id * from create_battery_asset();
        select create_battery_component(batt_id);
        select replace_uav_battery(uav_id, batt_id);
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

All attempts have led to the same error message. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: been too long since I coded in PGsql... but I think you got this part wrong: `select into batt_id * from create_battery_asset();` you can't `select into` a field name (that belongs to knowhere by the way) and then a `*`

Comment: try : `batt_id = create_battery_asset();` it is already a function, you can just assign its return value to the variable directly IIRC.

Comment: Replace `select` with `perform` in `select create_battery_component(batt_id);` The same in the next line.

Comment: The problem is always the same: you cannot have a `SELECT` statement without `INTO` in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - It's interesting why the `execute a_function()` in the answer below works fine. Whether it's a side effect or intended behavior, it should be officially documented (and it isn't).

Comment: @klin That won't work. It will call the function and try to execute the result as an SQL statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I thought so too but [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/TiaND6-_)

Comment: @klin Ah, but only for functions returning `void`. The empty statement is a valid one. You can also `EXECUTE '';`

Comment: Yes, that's clear. It's a side effect, a bit surprising but quite logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the return value helper function at all. I needed to change

```
        select create_battery_component(batt_id);
        select replace_uav_battery(uav_id, batt_id);
```

to

```
        execute create_battery_component(batt_id);
        execute replace_uav_battery(uav_id, batt_id);
```

Comment: That will only happen to work if both functions return `void` or an empty string. What this does is call the function and execute the result as an SQL statement. The correct way is to use `PERFORM`, as documented.